# Update error unexpected size

Tags: updates, appcenter, apt

**Input code** : `sudo apt update`
**Output with error** :

```
Get:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                               
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                    
Get:4 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                  
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]                                              
Get:6 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease [5,894 B]                                        
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]       
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Get:11 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 Packages [46.3 kB]
Get:12 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [126 kB]                
Get:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [299 kB]                          
Get:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [299 kB]                          
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Get:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [299 kB]                          
Err:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  File has unexpected size (248094 != 298652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:298652 [weak]
   - SHA256:28279b80d3def9b4e0ee1679bb35f1ad370ba08a0d06e7afffbb7ec89171a61e
   - SHA1:5674b2b15af03f4a9efe8c604588d7a29f18ff46 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ffe5f781ca6245ddfe9f862afc7f47f7 [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 05:06:12 +0000
Fetched 406 kB in 3s (137 kB/s)                                  
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  File has unexpected size (248094 != 298652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:298652 [weak]
    - SHA256:28279b80d3def9b4e0ee1679bb35f1ad370ba08a0d06e7afffbb7ec89171a61e
    - SHA1:5674b2b15af03f4a9efe8c604588d7a29f18ff46 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:ffe5f781ca6245ddfe9f862afc7f47f7 [weak]
   Release file created at: Tue, 12 Feb 2019 05:06:12 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Input code for list** :

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'
```

**Output list** :

```
[google-chrome.list] deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
[elementary.list] ppa:elementary-os/stable
[philip_scott-ubuntu-elementary-tweaks-bionic.list] ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
[appcenter.list] deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic main
[patches.list] ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
[linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-bionic.list] ppa:linrunner/tlp
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

**Image of Appcenter Error** :

[image: See the error]

**There is no apps which made for elementary os:**

[image]

> Thank you

Comment: Seeing the `Unable to lock directory` indicate that there are 2 update processes that block each other. Have you tried waiting for a while and then trying it again?

Comment: oops.sorry actually i posted wrong image, This is the actual error  "....E: Failed to fetch http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz File has unexpected size (248094 != 298652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]...." You the size is miss match 64x64 icon. I tried -rm the sources.list but not helped

Comment: Could you update the image in the question as well? To keep things clear. 
Could you run the following command, it should give a list of your software sources `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'`
Please include the result in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As the log says, it may have been because the mirror was stuck while syncing. If you run your original `sudo apt update` command it should now be fine.

If an error still occurs, you can try removing the apt cache with the following command:

```
sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: This error show every time ---   Err:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  File has unexpected size (248094 != 298652). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.28.5.44 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:298652 [weak]
   - SHA256:28279b80d3def9b4e0ee1679bb35f1ad370ba08a0d06e7afffbb7ec89171a61e
   - SHA1:5674b2b15af03f4a9efe8c604588d7a29f18ff46 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:ffe5f781ca6245ddfe9f862afc7f47f7 [weak]
  Release file created at

Comment: @RajeshSarker I have updated my answer with additional commands.